# No-free-lunch theorem and finite hypothesis class

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

I know that a finite hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$ is PAC-learnable. Let's say I take a binary classification with a finite set of input : $\mathcal{X}$ finite and $\mathcal{Y}=\{0;1\}$.

Then the set of all functions from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathcal{Y}$ is also finite and thus is PAC-learnable.

However, the No-free-lunch theorem states that, for $m$ samples, if $|\mathcal{X}|=2m$ then we have a distribution $\mathcal{D}$ such that $P(L_{D}(\hat{h}) \geq L_{D}(h^*) + \frac{1}{8} ) \geq \frac{1}{7} $

Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: There are several theorems called "the no free lunch theorem". Could you be more specific? In particular, what is $L_D$?

Comment: L_{D} is the expected loss : $L_{D}(h) = E(l(h(X),Y)$ where l is the loss. Here it is the binary loss : $l(h(X),Y) = 1[h(X) \neq Y]$. I took the theorem from this course : https://webdav.tuebingen.mpg.de/is-class-2/Lecture4.pdf

Comment: You may have more luck on the [compsci stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You're misunderstanding the definition of PAC learnability (re-read this, just so we're on the same page. In particular, note the notion of sample complexity developed within). For a hypothesis class to be PAC learnable, all we need is that there is some finite sample complexity of PAC learning it (for each $\epsilon, \delta,$ there exists $n(\epsilon, \delta)\cdots$). The NFL theorem above simply says that the class is not PAC learnable with sample complexity $|\mathcal{X}|/2.$ There is some larger number of samples you need to supply in order for the PAC learning guarantees to hold.

Comment: Why is this relevant? There may be some subclasses of the set of all binary functions from $\mathcal{X} \to \{0,1\}$ that in fact are learnable with $|\mathcal{X}|/2$ samples (e.g. suppose $\mathcal{X} = \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ and let $\mathcal{H}'$ be the set of single threshold classifiers. Excercise - find the sample complexity of this class). In fact, there may be many such subclasses.(contd.)

Comment: This might suggest that the whole class is learnable with such few samples. The NFL theorem is saying that no, just because you can find the best hypotheses in a bunch of small collections, this does not mean that you can reliably find the best hypothesis overall with the same (small) number of examples.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 , isn't your first comment relevant only for finite $\cal{X}$?

Comment: I mean if $\cal{X}$ is infinite, then I read "the NFL theorem above simply says that the class is not PAC learnable with sample complexity |$\cal{X}$|/2." as "Any hypothesis class over an infinite domain is not PAC-learnable". Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Elnur Note that this question is explicitly dealing with finite $\mathcal{X}$, so the comments are in that context. In general, if you're asking whether there exist hypothesis classes over infinite domains are learnable, then the answer is yes - thresholds in $[0,1]$ are a classic example with sample complexity scaling as $1/\varepsilon^2$. Of course, the hypothesis class of all functions is not learnable, but this is trivial.